# How to activate an existing virtualenv projects?

Tags: python, django, windows, cmd

I'm a beginner to Django and Python, and I've never used virtualenv before. However, I do know the exact commands to activate and deactivate virtual environments (online search). However, this learning course takes time and sometimes I need to split the work over 2 days.

When I create a virtualenv today and do some work, I'm unable to access the same virtualenv tomorrow. Even when I navigate to that folder and type in `.\venv\Scripts\activate`, it says "system cannot find specific path".

How can I open already existing virtual environments and the projects within them? Could it be that I need to end my previous session in a certain way for me to access it the next time?

Comment: Can you please try use absolute path? like `C:\Users\YourName\Projects\venv\Scripts\activate`

Comment: Thanks @YangHG, but same issue

Comment: Have you moved the venv folder? While creating virtual env it puts full paths inside the related scripts. if you moved the folder i cannot be activated.

Comment: I tried both absolute path and relative path, it works fine. So I think you should consider @İsmailTahaAYKAÇ 's idea.

Comment: @İsmailTahaAYKAÇ I haven't moved any related folder.

Comment: Please provide the full error. So we could have a further idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though pipenv had so many problems. I suggest you use it when you are new to virtual env.

Just

```
pip install pipenv
cd $your-work-directory
pipenv shell
```

Then you created your project env.
You can active it by:

```
cd $your-work-directory
pipenv shell
```

You can install packages by:

```
cd $your-work-directory
pipenv install $yourpackage --skip-lock
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the command prompt
2. Go to the project directory, where you created virtual environment
3. And type the same as error shows, as in my  case it was

File D:\Coding files\Python****recommendation-system\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1**** cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

4. So I typed recommendation-system\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1

And it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and it will work:

`cd $working directory u have virtual env on`

`pipenv shell`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command it worked for me for reusing your existing venv

```
    $ workon then the name of your existing venv
```

Comment: `workon` is a command from `virtualenvwrapper`